# Onchange color picker not changing canvas background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, onchange

I'm trying to change the background of my canvas element for a school project based on user input from the color-picker. However I can't seem to get it to work. I've checked over the code and everything seems to be properly selected. Any ideas on why?

```
docolor() {
  var myCanvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
  var colorinput = document.querySelector("#clr");
  var color = colorinput.value;
  myCanvas.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```
  <head>
    <title> canvas practice </title>
   </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id = "myCanvas"> 
    </canvas> 
    <br>
    <input type = "color" value = "#001A57" id = "clr" onchange = "docolor()">
  </body>
</html>
```

-

```
#clr {
  display: inline-block;
}

#myCanvas {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docolor` isn't properly defined, so it never runs. Declare your function like this and it should work:

```
function docolor() {
  var myCanvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
  var colorinput = document.querySelector("#clr");
  var color = colorinput.value;
  myCanvas.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Let me know if it's still not working. [Here's a link to a working codepen](https://codepen.io/Varauk/pen/jONQqZa) if you want to see everything working together. Goodluck with your project!

Comment: Thanks for the codepen link. I added the function declaration and it still didn't work. Then checked the differences in our code and realized I had an extra undeclared function that was messing things up when I was trying to do the next part of the project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks you forgot the `function` declaretion.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title> canvas practice </title>
  <style>
    #clr {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    #myCanvas {
      height: 150px;
      width: 300px;
      border: 2px solid;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas">
  </canvas>
  <br>
  <input type="color" value="#001A57" id="clr" onchange="docolor()">
</body>
<script>
  function docolor() {
    var myCanvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
    var colorinput = document.querySelector("#clr");
    var color = colorinput.value;
    myCanvas.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
</script>

</html>
```